# Add Checkbox field in existing PDF, mark the value then make it readonly

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using the following code to add checkbox field to an existing PDF. Note the code is in C#, so might be a little different than in iText, but should share the same concept.

```
private void addCheckboxField( PdfStamper stamper, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, String name, int pagenumber, bool isChecked) 
{

        RadioCheckField field = new RadioCheckField(stamper.Writer, rect, name, "Yes");
        field.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
        field.Checked = isChecked;
        field.BorderWidth = BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_THIN;
        field.BorderColor= BaseColor.BLACK;
        field.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
        stamper.AddAnnotation(field.CheckField, pagenumber);
    }
```

Then I call this function to generate a checkbox in desired position of an existing PDF. Problem is the checkbox is not checked when passing true. Also the field is editable.
How can I check it and how can I make it readonly.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I get that resolved. field.Options+=RadioCheckField.READ_ONLY;